# Concatenating Attribute name for dynamic request

Tags: qgis, expression

I am using QGIS 3.12.0 and the expression editor.

The starting point is the following query:

```
round( (( "b_12052020" - "b_05052020" )/ "EWZ" )*100000)
```

The result is fine.

The feature database has one column for every day like `b_01052020` and `b_02052020` and so on. The main goal is an automatic calculation from today to 7 days back.

I used the following code in a single expression and the result is fine.

```
format_date( (now() - to_interval( '7 days')),'ddMMyyyy')
```

I create with concat a string, looks like the names of the columns.

```
concat( 'b_', format_date( (now() - to_interval( '7 days')),'ddMMyyyy'))
```

My problem, I can't bring them together. For an example, I show you a short version.

```
round( (( concat( 'b_', format_date( now(), 'ddMMyyyy')) - "b_05052020" )/ "EWZ" )*100000)
```

It brings me an error!

Also, adding Quotation Marks to the string brings no result.

```
round( (( concat( '"b_', format_date( now(), 'ddMMyyyy'),'"') - "b_05052020" )/ "EWZ" )*100000)
```

Is it possible to create dynamic table names for a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you are doing to construct the field name returns a string. To convert this string (column name) to the feature value, it would have to be evaluated using the function `attribute`:

```
attribute('osm' || '_id')  
--> build the string 'osm_id' and return the value for the current feature.
```

[image]